# Qt - How to override a widget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtgui

I've created a form using the Qt designer which includes a QToolButton.
I can turn it using `ui->favouriteToolButton`.
I used the designer because it's much more simple then code all the gui.

Problem is that specifically for this `ToolButton` i want to code by creating its own class:

```
class FavouriteMenu : public QToolButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FavouriteMenu(QWidget *parent = 0);
    //~FavouriteMenu();

private:
    QMenu *menu;                                        //MENU
    QAction *addToBookmarkAct;
    QAction *editBookmarkAct;

...
```

I want to be able to override `ui->favouriteToolButton` with a new instance of FavouriteMenu.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Right click on the button in designer and select "Promote To..."
- Under Promoted class name enter "FavouriteMenu"
- Under Header File enter the filename of the .h file
- Click "Add"
- Click "Promote"

Comment: i did so but the old button still spears
and more weird than that - i even removed the button from the designer and recompiled and it still there...

Comment: no matter what change i do in the designer and recompile i get the same gui

Comment: Make sure all the intermediate files get rebuilt

Comment: anything i can do except for 'Clean All' and then 'Rebuild All' ?

Comment: Without knowing what development environment you are using we can't know, but the .ui file gets converted into code, testwindow.ui into ui_testwindow.[h|cpp] iirc, you should see the changes you specified in those files, i.e. the declaration `QToolButton *yourbuttonName` should be `FavouriteMenu *yourbuttonName` and the .h file with favorite menu should be in the include list. If those things are not true, then the .ui file has not been refreshed, or you did not save your changes